# Spring FactoryBean without any Spring imports

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to create a POJO bean that would / could be treated by Spring as a `FactoryBean`. So I would like to create a class that is a `FactoryBean` (has `getObject`, `getType`, `isSingleton`, etc) but does not import ANY Spring-specific classes. Therefore it would not implement `FactoryBean`.

FYI, using a `factory-method` would not work because I need to set properties prior to creating the object.

A classic example of this would be using a builder where you create the builder, set properties and call a build method to get the final bean required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the builder has proper Java Beans compatible `set` methods for its properties then you can do it in two stages

```
<bean id="fooBuilder" class="com.example.FooBuilder">
  <property name="algorithm" value="simple" />
</bean>

<bean id="foo" factory-bean="fooBuilder" factory-method="build" />
```

But for something like a [Guava CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) that uses fluent setters you're probably better off using Spring's [JavaConfig approach](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) for that part of the configuration instead of XML

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  public @Bean Cache<String, MyObject> cache() {
    return CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
      .maximumSize(1000)
      .softValues()
      .build(cacheLoader);
  }

  // defined elsewhere, maybe in XML
  private @Autowired CacheLoader<String, MyObject> cacheLoader;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about *factory-bean*? For example:

```
<bean id="factory" class="package.Factory">
    <!-- configure properties here -->
</bean>
<bean id="instance" factory-bean="instans" factory-method="createInstance"/>
```

Spring will create instance of Factory class, configure it and the use it's *createInstance* method to create bean with id *instans*.